# Duplicate references when reusing the same component in Sencha app

Tags: extjs

Suppose we have defined a component (e.g. FieldSet) that we'd like to reuse in the single app (e.g. display/use it in 2 different modal windows.) This FieldSet has a reference, which we use to access it. The goal is to have these 2 windows contain **independent** fieldsets, so we can control and collect the inputs from each one separately.

Here's the sample [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dhu) that demonstrates the problem. As soon as any function triggers any `lookupReference(...)` call, Sencha issues the warning for "Duplicate reference" for the fieldset. It correctly creates two distinct fieldset components (by assigning different ids) on each window, but fails to properly assign/locate the references. As a result, any actions on one of these windows' fieldsets would be performed on the "unknown" one (probably on the first created one), messing up the UI behavior.

I see how it is a problem for Sencha to understand which component to use when operating on the reference, but there should be a way to reuse the same component multiple times without confusing the instances. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why must your controller be a `singleton`?  That seems like a very strange thing to do.

Comment: That was an old design choice in the project to be able to easily control the elements from different places (not only from the related view.) do you think that might cause the issues?

Comment: It does cause the issue... I changed your logic to not be a `singleton`, and it didn't throw the warning.  Read the Summary section of [ViewController](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html)... it sounds like the singleton approach breaks how it was designed.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. How did you invoke the func() without the singleton?

Comment: Like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3di7)... added comments throughout, so you can see all changes.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll study your approach and get back. Thanks again, very helpful

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: All this makes perfect sense. I'll have to research more to incorporate this into the actual project but this definitely answers the question, so please post the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs on [ViewController](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html):

> A view controller is a controller that can be attached to a specific view instance so it can manage the view and its child components. Each instance of the view will have a new view controller, so the instances are isolated.

This means that your use of `singleton` on your ViewController isn't correct, as it must be tied to a single view instance.

To fix this, I'd recommend making some modifications to your [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3di7), mainly removing the `singleton: true` from your VC class, accessing the views through `lookup`, and getting their VC's through `getController` to access your `func` method.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {

        /**
         * @thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462770
         */
        Ext.define('fsContainerHandler', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.fsContainerHandler',
            // TOOK OUT singleton: true
            func: function () {
                var x = this.lookupReference('fsRef');
                alert(x);
            }
        });

        Ext.define('fsContainer', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            xtype: 'xFSContainer',
            controller: 'fsContainerHandler',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'myFieldset',
                reference: 'fsRef'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('mainContainerHandler', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.mainContainerHandler',
            singleton: true,
            onButton1Click: function () {
                var win = this.getView().window1;
                win.show();
                // CHANGED LOGIC
                win.lookup('theContainer').getController().func();
            },
            onButton2Click: function () {
                var win = this.getView().window2;
                win.show();
                // CHANGED LOGIC
                win.lookup('theContainer').getController().func();
            }
        });

        Ext.define('mainContainer', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            width: 400,
            controller: 'mainContainerHandler',
            window1: null,
            window2: null,
            initComponent: function () {
                this.window1 = Ext.create('window1');
                this.window2 = Ext.create('window2');
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Window 1',
                reference: 'btn1',
                handler: mainContainerHandler.onButton1Click,
                scope: mainContainerHandler
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Window 2',
                reference: 'btn2',
                handler: mainContainerHandler.onButton2Click,
                scope: mainContainerHandler
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('window1', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'Window1',
            modal: true,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            // ADDED referenceHolder
            referenceHolder: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'xFSContainer',
                // ADDED reference
                reference: 'theContainer'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('window2', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'Window2',
            modal: true,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            // ADDED referenceHolder
            referenceHolder: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'xFSContainer',
                // ADDED reference
                reference: 'theContainer'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('mainContainer', {
            renderTo: document.body
        });
    }
});
```